# US Account Taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction

I'm an Australian resident with a US brokerage account. At what point would have to pay taxes in the US after realising gain through my brokerage account?

Comment: Are you a US resident? It is **your** income is taxed, not the account's. Are **you** under the US jurisdiction? If not, the only US-sourced income is dividends, and you're probably already paying more than the actual tax through withholdings